# this.setState is not actually setting my state at all?

Tags: reactjs

I am currently creating a small React app for a shopping list. I am attempting to hold the list items as state. Once the input is submitted, for adding a new item, a function is called, which sends the new list to the App and also attempts to reset the state to ''. For some reason this is not working. I checked through logging and also I can tell by the fact that my input does not reset.

Here is the code:

```
class List extends React.Component {
  state = {newItem: ''};

  addItem = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    this.props.onSubmit(this.state.newItem);
    this.setState({newItem: ''});
  }


  render() {
      return (
        <div>
          {this.props.currentUser.shoppingList.map(item => 
            <ListItem 
              {...item} 
              updatedList={this.props.updatedList}
            />)}
            <form onSubmit={this.addItem}>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Add new item!" 
                value={this.state.newItem}
                onChange={event => this.setState({newItem: event.target.value})}
              />
              <button>Save</button>
            </form>
        </div>
      );
    }
}
```

Comment: bind `this` to your method: `<form onSubmit={this.addItem.bind(this)}`

Comment: @JosanIracheta if you define addItem as an arrow function as in the example, you don't need to bind it to this

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're not binding `this` to the `addItem` function.

Try changing `<form onSubmit={this.addItem}>`

To `<form onSubmit={this.addItem.bind(this)}>`

Comment: You don't need to bind the method to this, if you use public class fields syntax: https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Answer (score 0):

Your state is working perfectly. Problem may be with your `props`. Here is the working sample except `ListItem`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>React State</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/jsx">
        class List extends React.Component {
            state = {newItem: ''};

            addItem = event => {
                event.preventDefault();
                console.log(this.state.newItem);
                this.setState({newItem: ''});
            }

            render() {
                return (
                    <div>
                        <form onSubmit={this.addItem}>
                          <input type="text" placeholder="Add new item!" 
                            value={this.state.newItem}
                            onChange={event => this.setState({newItem: event.target.value})}
                          />
                          <button>Save</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                );
            }
        }

        ReactDOM.render(
          <List />, 
          document.getElementById("app")
        );
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```